# Convert first rows of column value as header or turn rows and convert them in headers

Tags: python, pandas

I want convert only first 2 values of the first column of my df into header or turn that values as column/row.

I mean, I have this

```
0       1      2
Person  7.8    10
Person2 6      11
```

But I want get this

```
Person  Person2
7.8     6
10      11
```

Comment: If your dataframe is named `df` try `df.T`.

Comment: It doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if first column is not `index` use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), transpose, create default index and last remove columns name:

```
df = df.set_index(0).T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

else:

```
df = df.T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Comment: I get this error: 'None of [0] are in the columns'

Comment: @LanderIturregi - So need second solution? Or `'0'` like `df.set_index('0').T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)` ?

Comment: I need second one, but Person rows (Columns now) they are not as header, they are as 0 index row

Comment: @LanderIturregi So need `df.set_index('0').T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None, axis=1)` ? If not working, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: If I use your second code, and after that individually these: #header_row = 0
#prueba.columns = prueba.iloc[header_row]
#prueba.drop(index=0, inplace=True) I can change it, thanks!